# No me permite actualizar el usuario

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, phpmyadmin

tengo un problema resulta que al iniciar session si el usuario es nuevo tendra la columna de levely vacia pero si no lo manda a otra ruta entonces si es nuevo lo tendra que validar una vez validado me manda a la seccion para actualizar password en esta seccion se toma como referencia el login que inicio pero resulta que no me reconoce el usuario como tal y me manda vacio los campos

adjunto los errores

```
Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\SERVICES\registro\contraseña.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\SERVICES\registro\contraseña.php on line 39
La informacion se actualizo con exitostring(98) "UPDATE useros SET clave='AQUI DEBE TENER' ,fecha_registro='2020-08-03',levely='2' WHERE usuario=''"
```

y el codigo es el siguiente

```
<?php
session_start();

include("../configuracion.php");

date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');




/* comprobar la conexión */
$nom=$_SESSION['usuario'];

/* cerrar la conexión */
$hoy = date("Y-m-d");  

//Conecto a mi base de datos

//Cadena de consulta que me devuelve todos los registros de la tabla 'users'
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];//le asigno una variable 
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM useros WHERE id =".$id; //cadena de consulta para el elemento $id
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query1)){ //si obtengo resultados ejecutando la consulta anterior
        while($usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ //asigno ese resultado a un array asociativo $user
            $clave = $usuario['clave']; //creo variables con los nombres de los campos de la tabla "users" 
            $levely = $usuario['levely'];
        
        }
    }

}



if(isset($_POST['sw']) == 1){ //si se ha presionado el boton "Actualizar" 

    //cadena con la orden de actualizacion a la tabla "users" con los valores de los inputs enviados por POST
    $query2 = "UPDATE useros SET clave='".$_POST['clave']."' ,fecha_registro='$hoy',levely='".$_POST['levely']."' WHERE usuario='".$_SESSION['usuario']."'";

    if(mysqli_query($link, $query2)){ //si la consulta se ejecuta con exito
        echo "La informacion se actualizo con exito"; //mensaje de exito
        var_dump($query2);

        //header('Location: ../index.php'); //redireccion a index.php
    }else{ //si ocurrio un error
        echo "Ocurrio un error al intentar actualizar"; //mensaje de error
    }
}
    /* liberar el conjunto de resultados */



//zona horaria por defecto


//cierro conexion a bbdd
mysqli_close($link);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Crea una contraseña No sera necesario cambiarla despues</title>
<?php
 echo "<center><h4 class='tabita'>". "Bienvenido \ a: " . $nom ."&nbsp; " ."</h4></center>" . "\n\n";

?>
<!-- Meta tag Keywords -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Account Register Form Responsive Widget,Login form widgets, Sign up Web forms , Login signup Responsive web form,Flat Pricing table,Flat Drop downs,Registration Forms,News letter Forms,Elements" />
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false);
function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<!-- Meta tag Keywords -->
<!-- css files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> <!-- Style-CSS --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css"> <!-- Font-Awesome-Icons-CSS -->
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,400i,700,700i&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,devanagari,greek,greek-ext,latin-ext,vietnamese" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- //css files -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- main -->
<div class="w3ls-header">
    <h1>Crea una contraseña No sera necesario cambiarla despues</h1>
    <div class="header-main">
            <div class="header-bottom">
                <div class="header-right w3agile">
                    <div class="header-left-bottom agileinfo">
                        <form action="contraseña.php" method="POST">
                        
                            
                            <div class="icon1">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="clave" required/>
                            </div>
                        
    

                            <select name="levely" required>
    <option name="levely" value=""  placeholder="">selecciona el cargo</option>
    <option value="3">Supervisor</option>
    <option value="1">Auxiliar Administrativo ( analista de bases)</option>
    <option value="2" >Administrador</option>
    
    </select>
                            <div class="bottom">
                            <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="actualizar" value="Actualizar" /><br /><br />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php if(isset($id)) echo $id; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="sw" value="1" />
                            </div>
                        
                    </form> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--header end here-->
<!-- copyright start here -->

<!--copyright end here-->
</body>
</html>
```

entonces la cuestion es que no me deja actualizar el usuario que le corresponde con un update solo me aparece en que no tiene el usuario logeado no se bine por que

Comment: No-respuesta: estás armando las consultas de forma que las hace inseguras, vulnerables a SQL injection, además de fallar desastrosamente cuando el POST no llega con las variables que espera. Procura usar prepared statements.

Comment: aja??? pero etonces es tema de el id que se manda o ?

Comment: ok editare la pregunta

Comment: Eh, ahora quitaste el código relevante y no se sabe nada del update que te falla. Pero sí, la respuesta a tu pregunta es que, en alguna parte, estás buscando un `$algo['usuario']` que no existe

Comment: Si el error persiste, esa variable de sesión está llegando vacía